# A drive with the name C does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list the latest folder created on a powershell script:

```
$cmdOutput= dotnet nuget locals global-packages --list
$nugetPath = "$cmdOutput" -split 'info : global-packages: '
$orchFolder = "$nugetPath" + "myDllFolder"
echo $orchFolder # C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\myDllFolder
$latestFolder = Get-ChildItem -Directory $orchFolder
```

When using the above script, I am getting this error: `Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ' C' does not exist`
Even if my C drive exists.

I know there are questions related to this issue. But it did not help.

Note that when I replace this line:

- `$latestFolder = Get-ChildItem -Directory $orchFolder`

  with this one:
- `$latestFolder = Get-ChildItem -Directory The_Same_Path_Printed_On_The_Echo_Command (C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\myDllFolder)`

It is working perfectly fine!

Which makes me think there is something wrong when I pass the variable directly. I tried to pass it through double quote, but still same error.

Any idea on what am I missing ?

Comment: The `-split` operation results in an empty string + the string you want - when turned into a string with `""` that results in a space in front of `C:`. Change to `$nugetPath = ("$cmdOutput" -split 'info : global-packages: ')[1]`

Comment: Indeed... A stupid error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but why would it does so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not on this line:

```
$latestFolder = Get-ChildItem -Directory $orchFolder
```

I believe the problem is in the way you are parsing the output returned by the previous commands.

```
$cmdOutput= dotnet nuget locals global-packages --list
$nugetPath = "$cmdOutput" -split 'info : global-packages: '
$orchFolder = "$nugetPath" + "myDllFolder"
```

Notice the extra space around the ' C'  in your error message.

Comment: Yes as mentioned by @Mathias, the comment on my post: the issue was on my split. Taking his answer fixed the issue.